# Angular 2 Not redirecting to Dashboard

Tags: angular2-routing

I have the below in my route:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'dashboard' },
    { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
];
```

After logging in, I have a white screen until I click on Dashboard Menu. My default Url goes to: https://localhost:44333/ Instead of https://localhost:44333/dashboard

I have checked other examples online and I cannot understand what is wrong with my router. Am I missing out something please?

Comment: move ** path to the end.

Comment: @Antoniossss I did, still same result :(

Answer (score 1):

Why your dashboard has empty path specified   `{ path: '', component: DashboardComponent}` ?? Try

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'dashboard' },
];
```